# How to display :text value in twitter output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

So in my ArticlesController I set this...

```
@most_recent_tweets = Twitter.home_timeline(count:1)
```

and in the articles index.html.erb file...

```
    <% @most_recent_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
        <%= tweet["attrs"] %>
    <% end %>
```

This works fine...I get the following output...

```
{:created_at=>"Mon Nov 26 04:45:31 +0000 2012", :id=>272924019395813376, :id_str=>"272924019395813376", :text=>"Episode 394: STI and Polymorphic Associations (pro) http://t.co/UrLLdY1n", :source=>".....etc}
```

So here is my question..how do I display only the value for :text?

I want my output to be....

```
Episode 394: STI and Polymorphic Associations (pro) http://t.co/UrLLdY1n
```

How do I do this? (thank you for your time)

Comment: Hi @thefonso - this is great, but it's really an "answer" to your question. It's best to put it in the answer section so that people know that your problem has been solved. Yes, it's ok to answer (and even accept) your own question.

Answer (score 0):

got it...tweet["text"]

so....

```
<% @most_recent_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <%= tweet["attrs"] %>
<% end %>
```

becomes...

```
<% @most_recent_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <%= tweet["text"] %>
<% end %>
```